# Data Studio - RSS feed possible?

Tags: looker-studio

Has anyone tried integrating an RSS feed into data studio? If so, how?

I have tried searching the connectors for 'rss'. No results. Google shows a few third party integrations that appear to cost $. Not sure that's the best route.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [open source RSS connector](https://github.com/googledatastudio/community-connectors/pull/8/files). You will need to deploy it yourself.

Comment: This looks promising. I'm going to take a look soon.

Comment: the connector links embeded in your link are invalid. i cannot find the connector source you're referring to

Answer (score 0):

As I don't see a direct connector in Data Studio, I am solving this by  using Google spreadsheets function `=IMPORTFEED`. Spreadsheets did a great job at parsing the RSS feed I fed it. After I have the data in spreadsheets, I can easily connect it to DS.